# How to use app.config with ilmerge executable

Tags: c#, app-config, ilmerge

My merge project combines a few custom dll's with an executable. I have done the merge with both command line ilmerge utility, and IL Merger Tool but have yet to get the config part working.

My exe uses using `System.Configuration` to read in a connection string, like so:

`DataAccess da = new DataAccess(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ProviderName,                                         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString);`

When trying to run the produced executable, it bombs on the above line with the following error `Object Reference not set to an instance of object`.

I am assuming this is because the merged executable can't find the config file.

If that is the case, what do I need to do to ensure the config file is wired in?

If not, what else could the issue be? By the way, the unmerged executable works fine in debug.

Comment: Can you show the result of merge? I mean the files you are getting as a result?

Comment: Sure. Say for output I want MyExecutable.exe. After running the utility, in my specified output directory, the files are `MyExecutable.exe`, `MyExecutable.pdb`, `MyExecutable.log` (log file came with IL Merger Tool).

Comment: Bu clearly you are missing .exe.config file there.

Comment: Yes it is not there. I have tried manually copying the config to output directory, with both the name App.Config and MyExecutable.Config but the errors still occur.

Comment: Add the config via the Add New Item command in visual studio.  That gives you an app.config in your exe project that gets transformed to (and this is important) YourAppsName.EXE.config.

Comment: It is not `MyExecutable.Config` but `MyExecutable.Exe.Config` ;)

Comment: It was a bad name all along! Had to ensure .exe was in the name. Thanks to both of you. Anyone care to propose the answer?